# weaving two svg items

Tags: svg

I'm editing the SVG file in inkscape. How do I have the red loop overlap the top part of the blue tag like in the image above the svg?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate the loop

With the Bézier tool, draw a shape on top

Select the shape and the loop.

click *Path > Intersection*

[image]